# How to reverse check the parent in a dictionary YAML

Tags: dictionary, ansible, yaml

I have a dictionary that is the exact same structure as below.

Where I am struggling is in Ansible code, how would I go about a user enters `apple`, and I identify the type is fruit?
When a user enters `spinach`, Ansible identifies it as veggie?

Basically, how do I reverse check the parent in a dictionary? EDIT: after using selectattr, how do i assign that to one variable to use in the future ? currently, i get food_groups | selectattr('names', 'contains', food) | first).type: fruit as output, how do i only get FRUIT assigned to a variable?

```yaml
groups:
   - type: fruit
     names:
     - apple
     - oranges
     - grapes
   - type: veggie
     names:
     - broccoli
     - spinach
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) and the [`contains`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-contains-a-value) test of Ansible for this.

***Important note***: do not name your dictionary [`groups`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html), as you risk a collision with the special variable of the same name. Here, I named it `food_groups`.

So, the task of giving the type of food is as simple as:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: (food_groups | selectattr('names', 'contains', food) | first).type
```

*<sup>given that the food you want to assert is in a variable name `food`</sup>*

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
    - name: food
      prompt: What food to you want to know the group?
      private: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: (food_groups | selectattr('names', 'contains', food) | first).type
      vars:
        food_groups:
          - type: fruit
            names:
            - apple
            - oranges
            - grapes
          - type: veggie
            names:
            - broccoli
            - spinach
```

This yields:

```
What food to you want to know the group?: grapes

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  (food_groups | selectattr('names', 'contains', food) | first).type: fruit
```

Comment: All right, you were first ;)

Comment: @Zeitounator interesting, though, to see you doing `list | map(attr) | first` when I tend to do `(list | first).attr`. Your use of a default is also worthy.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also had a include_vars: file: myDict.yml for the dictionary since it is a different file. I get a "VARIABLE NOT DEFINED!" error when running the command you mentioned, could it be because i did include_vars to bring in the dict yaml? what change would i need in the code? maybe a .myDict.yml in the end ?

Comment: I just noticed when doing include_vars, ansible adds more lines in the dict like ansible_facts:  which probably messed it up

Comment: Works the same with an `include_vars`. Have you red the note about **not naming your dictionary `groups`**? Otherwise, [edit] your question or open a new one and pinpoint your actual issue.

Comment: It worked finally, thanks a lot

Comment: HI @β.εηοιτ.βε , i had a follow up question, how do i assign that output to one variable to use in the future ? currently, i get " food_groups | selectattr('names', 'contains', food) | first).type: fruit " as output, how do i only get FRUIT assigned to a variable? when i do set_fact, it still just outputs the whole thing... i edited the question also

Comment: `variable_to_assign: "{{ food_groups | selectattr('names', 'contains', food) | first).type }}"`. But for a different question, do not edit your actual question.

Comment: it worked, i appreciate the quick feedback, guess i was missing the quotes and curly brackets

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"**How would I go about a user entering 'apple', and I identify the type is 'fruit'?**"*

A: Create a dictionary mapping the items to groups, e.g. given the data

```yaml
    my_groups:
      - type: fruit
        names:
          - apple
          - oranges
          - grapes
          - tomato
      - type: veggie
        names:
          - broccoli
          - spinach
          - tomato
```

The task below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_dict: "{{ my_dict|d({'undef': 'undef'})|
                     combine({item.1: [item.0.type]}, list_merge='append') }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ my_groups }}"
        - names
```

gives

```yaml
  my_dict:
    apple: [fruit]
    broccoli: [veggie]
    grapes: [fruit]
    oranges: [fruit]
    spinach: [veggie]
    tomato: [fruit, veggie]
    undef: undef
```

I added 'tomato' to both groups to test the membership in multiple groups. The identification of the item's groups is now trivial, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_item|d('undef') }} is {{ my_dict[my_item|d('undef')]|d('none') }}"
```

gives by default

```yaml
  msg: undef is undef
```

When you enter an item not present in the dictionary you get

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e my_item=foo
...
  msg: foo is none
```

and when you enter an item present in the dictionary you get the group(s)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e my_item=spinach
...
  msg: spinach is ['veggie']
```